# javascript into "external" file

Tags: javascript, external

Rookie question:

How can I change below script into: < script src="file-here.js">< /script>
Can I remove the window load and document ready function?

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(window).load(function(){
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.dropdown').click(function(){
                var dropdownDiv = $(this).parent();
                $('ul', dropdownDiv).slideToggle('fast');
            });
            $('body').click(function(){  
            }); 
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

Comment: putting the script in separate file should just work fine.

Comment: Refer this page:
http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/external.shtml

Comment: @user1882080 What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just put it in an external file: `file-here.js`

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.dropdown').click(function(){
            var dropdownDiv = $(this).parent();
            $('ul', dropdownDiv).slideToggle('fast');
        });
        $('body').click(function(){  
        }); 
    });
});
```

and replace it by `<script src="file-here.js"></script>`

***UPDATE:***

about the load/ready functions this should suffice:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.dropdown').click(function(){
        var dropdownDiv = $(this).parent();
        $('ul', dropdownDiv).slideToggle('fast');
    });
    //note that this handler is empty and doing nothing (you can leave it out)
    $('body').click(function(){

    }); 
});
```

Comment: looks like it works, really thought these doc ready and window load needed to be cut out, thx

Answer (score 1):

> How can I change below script into: `< script src="file-here.js">< /script>`

1. Select text between (and not including) the start and end script tags
2. Click Cut
3. Open a new file
4. Click Paste
5. Save

> Can I remove the window load and document ready function?

Not without changing what the code does (although binding to `ready` *after* binding to `load` is silly. `ready` fires **before** `load`, but that is orthogonal to using an external script).

Comment: You should also include shortcuts for cut paste and save

Answer (score 1):

Move the source to the .js file, remove the first and last line (`<script> and </script>`).

You can probably remove `$(window).load(function(){` but `ready` is required to make sure the code executes only when the dom has been fully loaded.